# Comparison between day of week in oracle

Tags: oracle, date

I have problems with comparing the day of week

Here is my query in oracle database.

```
  SELECT DAY, WEEKDAY
    FROM (SELECT v.TNI, v.FRMP, v.LR, v.DAY, v.HH, v.VOLUME,
    CASE WHEN hd.HOLIDAY_DATE is not null then 'HOLIDAY'
    ELSE to_char(v.DAY, 'Day') END AS WEEKDAY
    FROM v_nem_rm16 v
    LEFT JOIN DBP_ADMIN.DBP_HOLIDAY hd 
    ON v.DAY = hd.HOLIDAY_DATE
    WHERE v.STATEMENT_TYPE != 'FORECAST')
  WHERE WEEKDAY = 'Monday';
```

Basically, the "WEEKDAY" column has the day of week based on the "DAY". Day is just date like 13/Mar/17
If you look at the "CASE" statement, you will notice that the "WEEKDAY" column is filled by "to_char(v.DAY, 'Day')". 
So the column has values like "Sunday, Saturday and so on, the day of week".


The problem is the outer query's where clause, "WHERE WEEKDAY = 'Monday'"
When I execute this query, It does not give me any rows even if I have rows having Monday as the value in "WEEKDAY" column

But when I change the WHERE clause to "WHERE WEEKDAY = to_char(sysdate, 'Day')", It works fine. The sql statement gives me the rows having "Saturday" in "WEEKDAY" column since the "to_char(sysdate, 'Day')" gives me "Saturday".

So what is problems with my first query??

I just want to filter rows by the name of the day of week like if i pass "Monday", i want to have all the rows having " Monday" in "WEEKDAY" column.

How can I do??

THANKS GUYS

Comment: Try `to_char(v.DAY, 'fmDay')`. Be aware, result depends on current session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` value which may change at any time.

Answer (score 1):

It appears TO_CHAR(, 'Day') returns a fixed length string with right side padding of blanks.  So, you are not getting 'Monday', you are really getting 'Monday   '.  The longest day is 'Wednesday', so it is a 9 character string.  So, either trim the value or compare against 'Monday   ' exactly.

```
select '|'||to_char(sysdate+level,'Day') ||'|' days_of_the_week
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

Results...

```
|Saturday |
|Sunday   |
|Monday   |
|Tuesday  |
|Wednesday|
|Thursday |
|Friday   |
```

Comment: Thanks you are right um can I ask one more stuff?? is there any kind of static variable for the day of week in oracle? because I don't want to use hardcode of "Monday, Tuesday...and so on". Or should I explicitly define?

Comment: @Michael Good question.  I don't know if static constants exist or not.  Try creating a new question on that.  In the mean time, you could alternatively use the 'DY' date format, which is the 3 char short name for the day such as  'MON' or jus the 'D' date formation, which is the number of the day of the week (sunday = 1), so Monday would be '2'.

Comment: Try `'fmDay'` instead of `Day`. Then the result is not padded with blanks.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  Correct, I forgot about that as I've not used it personally.  Adding 'fm' toggles off fill mode, which will eliminate the trailing blanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to use the day names (either full or abbreviated), I suggest to specify the language in the to_char function as follows:

```
select '|'||to_char(sysdate+level, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') ||'|' days_of_the_week_enu,
       '|'||to_char(sysdate+level, 'fmDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = German') ||'|' days_of_the_week_ger,
       '|'||to_char(sysdate+level, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') ||'|' days_of_the_week_abbr_enu,
       '|'||to_char(sysdate+level, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = German') ||'|' days_of_the_week_abbr_ger
from dual
connect by level <= 7;
```

This way the returned day names will be independent of session locale settings.

Result:
[image]